# Can't decipher Regex value

Tags: regex

I'm trying to work out how to apply ordering parameters in a URL. The regex for it is this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]*)\\s*(ASC|DESC)?$/
```

It is intended to be used like this: `order=` then the field, which is matched by the first part of the expression. But I don't get how to apply the ASC or DESC. So let's say, I have a field `title`, how can I order it by `title DESC`?

E.g.

```
?order=title ...what comes next?
```

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking for 0 or more whitespaces after the field.  (I think it should be one or more spaces; it could be a bug.)  Then, ASC or DESC.  Since some servers do not accept spaces in URLs, use the URL encoding code for space (%20):

```
?order=title%20DESC
```